# conditionally replace first value in a group by data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have quite a simple question.  I have long data that is in the following format:

```
ID    start.date    drug.start    drug.stop
1     01/02/2002    15/03/2004    16/04/2004
1     01/02/2002    16/04/2004    15/05/2004
...
2     05/01/2001    05/01/2001    06/02/2001
....
```

From the above example ID `1`'s `drug.start` is more than 2 years after their overall `start.date`, whereas ID `2` has the two dates as the same.  There are some other ID's in the data that are the same as ID `1`.

What I want to do is change the first `drug.start` for each ID to the `start.date`.

My current attempt is:

```
DT[, drug.start[1]:=start, by=ID]
```

to which I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'drug.start' not found
```

I'm quite new to `data.table` and not quite sure how to get what I want.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: There is a feature request posted for the way you tried to do it, fyi: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/571

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use row indexing.  We get the row index (`.I`) of the first value for each 'ID' (assuming it is already ordered and the columns are 'character' class), and use this index to assign the 'start.date' values to 'drug.start'

```
indx <- DT[, .I[1L], by=ID]$V1
DT[indx, drug.start := start.date]
DT
#   ID start.date drug.start  drug.stop
#1:  1 01/02/2002 01/02/2002 16/04/2004
#2:  1 01/02/2002 16/04/2004 15/05/2004
#3:  2 05/01/2001 05/01/2001 06/02/2001
#4:  2 05/02/2001 05/03/2001 06/05/2001
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
start.date = c("01/02/2002", 
"01/02/2002", "05/01/2001", "05/02/2001"), drug.start = c("15/03/2004", 
"16/04/2004", "05/01/2001", "05/03/2001"), drug.stop = c("16/04/2004", 
"15/05/2004", "06/02/2001", "06/05/2001")), .Names = c("ID", 
"start.date", "drug.start", "drug.stop"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

DT <- as.data.table(df1)
```